# how to fix wxpython menuitem short cut for "ctrl+," but label should display as "Ctrl+Comma"

Tags: wxpython, keyboard-shortcuts

developing wxpython desktop app , this required a menu item which show display the  label as "SomeXXX\tCtrl+Comma" , when i execute this app and i hit "Ctrl+," , is not working.

wx.MenuItem(self.tMn,wx.ID_ANY,text="SomeXXX\tCtrl+Comma",kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL,helpString="SomeXXX")  --- this code label is correct , but Ctrl+, is not working.

wx.MenuItem(self.tMn,wx.ID_ANY,text="SomeXXX\tCtrl+,",kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL,helpString="SomeXXX") ---- this line of code Ctrl+, shortcut is  working ,but menuitem text  is also displaying as "SomeXXX Ctrl+,"

How to display the menuitem text as "SomeXXX  Ctrl+Comma" and the shortcut should work with "Ctrl+,"

wx.MenuItem(self.tMn,wx.ID_ANY,text="SomeXXX\tCtrl+Comma",kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL,helpString="SomeXXX")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `wx.AcceleratorTable`. Then you can name the menu item the way you want. Here is an example (without a menu):

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Accelerator Tutorial", 
                          size=(500,500))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        randomId = wx.NewId()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onKeyCombo, id=randomId)
        accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord(','), 
                                          randomId )])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)

    def onKeyCombo(self, event):
        """"""
        print("You pressed CTRL+COMMA!")

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And here are a couple of links on the topic:

- https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.AcceleratorTable.html
- [wxPython: All About Accelerators](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/09/28/wxpython-all-about-accelerators/)
- [wxPython: Keyboard Shortcuts (Accelerators)](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/)

**Update** - I did a bit more research and found a solution for doing it with just a menu item. You can to call **SetAccel** and pass in the accelerator to make it work:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Accelerator Tutorial", 
                          size=(500,500))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu = wx.Menu()
        my_id = wx.NewId()
        comma_item = file_menu.Append(my_id, 'Blah\tCtrl+Comma', 
                                      'The comma cmd')
        entry = wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord(','), my_id)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onKeyCombo, id=my_id)
        comma_item.SetAccel(entry)
        menubar.Append(file_menu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    def onKeyCombo(self, event):
        """"""
        print("You pressed CTRL+COMMA!")

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mike Driscoll for you reply , issue resolved with your reply. accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,ord(','), \
                                          menuItm.GetId())])
        self.exFrame.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
        above 2 lines of code resolved my issue. Thank you verymuch once again.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution does not present the `Short Cut` in the standard format i.e. at the far right of the menu item. It relies on the menu item containing just the text `SomeXXX Ctrl+Comma` and NOT `SomeXXX\tCtrl+Comma`. It will therefore look slightly out of place if other menu items have standard short cuts.

Comment: @AnanthReddipalli If the answer above solved your issue, should should consider `Accepting` the answer by clicking on the greyed out tick on the left and/or click on the Up arrow to indicate that the answer was useful.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony - Good point. I updated the answer with a second solution

Comment: @MikeDriscoll On linux (at least) the combination of `\tCtrl+Any_non_valid_accelerator_key` results in `Debug: Unrecognized accel key 'comma', accel string ignored.` and the menu item's accelerator is blanked. Note: this is not a critisism just a note for others with a similar issue. Choose your accelerators wisely!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony - Yeah, I see that on Linux too, but the second example still works because I set the accelerator via `SetAccel`. As I recall, debug is turned on by default on Linux, which is probably why we are seeing that.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll That is queer, because when running that code I see `Blah     Ctrl+,` and not `Blah    Ctrl+Comma`. Maybe it's the version of wxpython I'm running (4.0.3 gtk2 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5)